# Initializing a 4bit input in system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Assume I have input logics suchs as: `x = 0, y= 1,z = 0,k = 1;`
I have an output: `output [3:0] reg result;` I want it to become 1010(kzyx) in binary. I tried

```
assign result = 4'kzyx;
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply concatenate this signals using `{}`:

```
assign result = {k,z,y,x};
```

A concatenation is the result of the joining together of bits resulting from one or more expressions (see more in IEEE1800-2017, ch. 11.4.12).

PS Notice that if you use `assign`, you should define your output as wire, not a reg.